# View the data that LoadPostData event is loading in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

What's the best way to view the data that LoadPostData event is loading to the controls in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually really simple. The NameValueCollection that get's passed to this method of EVERY control that implements the IPostbackDataHandler interface is the contents of Page.Request.Form. So you can access it at any time by getting a Watch on `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh... I would suggest setting your IDE environment up to [debug the .net framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx), and set a breakpoint on the LoadPostData() method of Control. That's a bit heavy-handed, but if you're willing to wade through the recursive calls to the Control class (perhaps set a conditional breakpoint on the method?), you will be able to get to the data that way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure you're looking at the data going into a particular control, you can subclass its control type and break during a custom implementation of `IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData`.

For example, you have a programmatically added control to collect the user's city. Change:

```
Public City As Textbox
```

to

```
Public City As BreakableLoadPostDataTextBox

Public Class BreakableLoadPostDataTextBox
  Inherits TextBox

  Protected Overrides Function LoadPostData( _
    ByVal postDataKey As String, _
    ByVal postCollection As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection) _
    As Boolean

    Return MyBase.LoadPostData(postDataKey, postCollection) ' Break here
  End Function
End Class
```

Set a breakpoint on the `Return` call. When execution breaks, you should be able to see the `postDataKey` that's being used to read the control's new value out of the `postCollection`. You can of course augment this method to your heart's content with Trace calls and whatnot.